# Better term for "time-evolving charts"

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

I am working on charts to show every day climate parameters such as temperature and precipitation over a period of time. I used the term "time-evolving charts". Is there a better term to show the evolution over time for these charts or diagrams? Besides, I want to use a better term for "climatic parameters"

Comment: "climatic parameters" sounds appropriate for this reason. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: yes, maybe you are right. But my main issue is finding a better term for the charts

Answer (score 3):

If you search for [images defined by "time series"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22time+series%22&hl=en&tbo=u&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ei=MUMSUfzLGsSOkwWmtoDYAQ&ved=0CEsQsAQ&biw=1235&bih=894), you will see that this is the common term for the types of chart you describe.

Answer (score 2):

You could use "***[Temporal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/temporal)-Climate***" *charts/diagrams*.

Answer (score 1):

The term *[time-lapse](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/time-lapse?q=time-lapse)* is used in describing a photographic technique

> denoting the photographic technique of taking a sequence of frames at set intervals to record changes that take place slowly over time. When the frames are shown at normal speed the action seems much faster.

While I am not aware of its application outside of actual photography, it could be adapted to your use in a phrase like *time-lapse climate charts*.  This would be especially appropriate if you intended to show them in rapid succession to reflect a changing patern.

As to *climate parameters*, if you wish to emphasize the change, you could say *climate trends* or *weather trends*.